# Get hostnames from ping and store results to text

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

Okay so here is the situation. I have a very large text file containing a lot of different IP addresses. I want to create a batch file, or anything that will get the job done, in order to resolve all of the host names for these IP addresses.

**Currently**, I have the IP Addresses stored one per line in a file called addresses.txt.

I also have a batch file with the following code:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (addresses.txt) do ping -a %%a >> PING_LOG.txt && (echo %%a Passed) || (echo %%a Failed)
pause
```

This seems to work okay. It fills my text file with all of the results from the ping; the hostname, the replies, the stats, packets, etc.

**Here is the problem:**
I *only* want the address I pinged and the hostname to be written to my output file. Is there any way I can accomplish this? Through the batch commands? Through other means (such as taking the output file and running it through something else to grab the information)? I am still actively trying to see what I can figure out, but any help would be immensely appreciated.

(The final goal is to place the host name and addresses in an excel spreadsheet side-by-side, and considering there are literally thousands of them doing it manually sounds terrible)

**MY FINAL SOLUTION**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (addresses.txt) do (
    set "_res=%%A"
    for /f "tokens=2" %%B in ('^(nslookup %%A ^) ^| findstr /c:"Name:"') do set "_res=!_res!, %%B"
    echo !_res! >> LOG.txt
    echo !_res!
)
endlocal
```

Thanks to Dmitry and Gravity for the help ^

Next, I took the data and dropped it into a spreadsheet (just one column). I wrote a macro script that looked at each cell, split the data into a string array using the comma as a delimeter, and then placed each resulting string into one column side by side (ip | name).

Comment: Pinging an IP address will not (usually) return the hostname of that IP address for you.  Sounds a bit more like `nslookup` functionality is what you need.. but you say that _"... fills my file with all of the results... **hostname**..."_  There are environments where some people see hostnames in `ping` results, but I wouldn't recommend using it here.

Comment: @gravity: `ping -a` usually does.

Comment: @gravity -a was getting the information I needed, but you are correct, nslookup is better. I totally forgot about that. I am going to try and rewrite the solution from Dmitry using nslookup and I'll post whatever I can come up with.

Comment: @Stephan - Not on my box, unfortunately, so it's environment-dependent, and therefore not reliable for retrieving hostnames.  "Usually," isn't a good dependency to have.

Comment: @gravity All of the addresses I am pinging are localish so it seems to work consistently. It is just exponentially slower than nslookup. However, so far I can not figure out how to grab the results from it like I could with the ping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `ping ...` command to `findstr` and then parse the output in the second `for` loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (addresses.txt) do (
    set "_res=%%A"
    for /f "tokens=2" %%B in ('^(ping -a %%A ^&^& echo --- ok^|^| echo --- failed^) ^| findstr /c:" [" /c:"---"') do set "_res=!_res!, %%B"
    echo !_res!
)
endlocal
```

For `addresses.txt`

```
8.8.8.8
88.88.77.77
```

will produce

```
8.8.8.8, google-public-dns-a.google.com, ok
88.88.77.77, ti0150a400-1603.bb.online.no, failed
```

Comment: NEARLY perfect solution. I needed the output to a text file, so I made this change: `echo !_res! >> LOG.txt` and it seems to be working. The only thing is, now I have no way to track the progress in the command window. Is there any way to output both to the command window and a text file?

Comment: Just add another `echo !_res!` after the first `echo`.

Comment: That worked. Another question for you. I am attempting to use nslookup. As far as I can tell the tokens only refer to the first line, and I can't seem to be able to grab any of the response information from the nslookup (or anything past 8 for the ping -a). How exactly does this work? (nslookup responds way faster, and considering there are thousands I think it would work better)

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('nslookup 8.8.8.8 2^>nul^|find "Name:"') do @echo %%i` (maybe you have to adapt `Name:` to your locale.)

Comment: `for` parses each line of a command or a file. To select lines to parse use `findstr`.

Comment: You can use `chcp 850 >nul` at the beginning of the script to switch to "Latin 1" code page. This will make `nslookup` to output text in English, so the script will work on PCs with different locales.